# TFS Folder Comparison Filters

Tags: tfs

I want to filter a folder name from a single sub-directory, not all folders from all sub-directories that happen to have the specified name.  For example, I have the following directory structure:

\trunk\Project1\Test\

and

\trunk\Project2\Test\

If I want to do a comparison on my machine against source control, but ignore just the \trunk\Project2\Test\ folder, I can't.  The only folder filter rule that would do anything is:

!Test\;

But that would cause the compare to ignore both Test folders, which I don't want.

See MSDN [Folder Comparison Filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385987.aspx).

(This is when you have the Source Control Explorer window tab open, then if you right click on a folder and choose the "Compare..." option, you'll get a dialog window that allows you to set the "Source Path", "Target Path", and "Filter:".  It is the Filters I'm adjusting, but it appears you can only provide leaf node folder names, not partial paths.)

Comment: Right click the test folder you want to ignore and cloak it, then check if it's ignored for the compare.